# Issue with Admob NativeExpressAdView in Recyclerview Implementation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, native-ads

I have already done lot of googling before asking this question here.

I have integrated NativeExpressAdView in my Recyclerview as described here in this [google example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample) and it is working fine too. But issue is, in this example project, they are adding NativeExpressAdView from zeroth position, but don't want to add NativeExpressAdView at zeroth position.

I can add at random position too, but issue comes when we have to set the adsize for the NativeExpressAdView from code.

Cardview, which is accessed in [MainActivity](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/nativeexpressrecyclerviewexample/MainActivity.java)'s `setUpAndLoadNativeExpressAds` method, will be Null and will give NPE if do not add view at zeroth position.

Here is my modified code snippet

```
/**
     * Adds Native Express ads to the items list.
     */
    private void addNativeExpressAds() {

        // Loop through the items array and place a new Native Express ad in every ith position in
        // the items List.
        for (int i = 7; i <= mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
            final NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(MainActivity.this);
            mRecyclerViewItems.add(i, adView);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets up and loads the Native Express ads.
     */
    private void setUpAndLoadNativeExpressAds() {
        // Use a Runnable to ensure that the RecyclerView has been laid out before setting the
        // ad size for the Native Express ad. This allows us to set the Native Express ad's
        // width to match the full width of the RecyclerView.
        mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final float scale = MainActivity.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                // Set the ad size and ad unit ID for each Native Express ad in the items list.
                for (int i = 7; i <= mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
                    final NativeExpressAdView adView =
                            (NativeExpressAdView) mRecyclerViewItems.get(i);
                    final CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.ad_card_view);
                    final int adWidth = cardView.getWidth() - cardView.getPaddingLeft()
                            - cardView.getPaddingRight(); //Here cardView will be Null (so NPE).
                    AdSize adSize = new AdSize((int) (adWidth / scale), NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_HEIGHT);
                    adView.setAdSize(adSize);
                    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
                }

                // Load the first Native Express ad in the items list.
                loadNativeExpressAd(7); //Not added code for this method as nothing is modified in that.
            }
        });
    }
```

This issue is coming even if i implement same changes after pulling the sample project code from repo.

Here is my logcat crash

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.example.nativeexpressrecyclerviewexample.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:106)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

So is this some kind of bug or i m doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

just add one more condition that

```
if (i!=0){}
```

in the both for loop
**update**:

```
  */
private void addNativeExpressAds() {

    // Loop through the items array and place a new Native Express ad in every ith position in
    // the items List.
    for (int i = 0; i <= mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
if(i!=0){
        final NativeExpressAdView adView = new NativeExpressAdView(MainActivity.this);
        mRecyclerViewItems.add(i, adView);
    }}
}

/**
 * Sets up and loads the Native Express ads.
 */
private void setUpAndLoadNativeExpressAds() {
    // Use a Runnable to ensure that the RecyclerView has been laid out before setting the
    // ad size for the Native Express ad. This allows us to set the Native Express ad's
    // width to match the full width of the RecyclerView.
    mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final float scale = MainActivity.this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            // Set the ad size and ad unit ID for each Native Express ad in the items list.
            for (int i = 0; i <= mRecyclerViewItems.size(); i += ITEMS_PER_AD) {
if(i!=0){
                final NativeExpressAdView adView =
                        (NativeExpressAdView) mRecyclerViewItems.get(i);
                final CardView cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.ad_card_view);
                final int adWidth = cardView.getWidth() - cardView.getPaddingLeft()
                        - cardView.getPaddingRight(); //Here cardView will be Null (so NPE).
                AdSize adSize = new AdSize((int) (adWidth / scale), NATIVE_EXPRESS_AD_HEIGHT);
                adView.setAdSize(adSize);
                adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
            }}

            // Load the first Native Express ad in the items list.
            loadNativeExpressAd(ITEMS_PER_AD); //Not added code for this method as nothing is modified in that.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you mean to say i keep initialization for loop from i=0 only and add if condition that if i != 0 add the NativeExpressAdView else not?

Comment: yes you have to start with 0 but by condition this avoid index 0

Comment: try to give static size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153512/discussion-between-rajen-raiyarela-and-jigar-savaliya).

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue , Please post the answer if you have resolved the issue

Comment: just use dependency wisely

Comment: @ jigar savaliya : I am able to load the ad properly , but I don't want to display the ad in the first position of recyclerview

Comment: yes , I have tried your code , but am getting  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.support.v7.widget.CardView.getWidth()' on a null object reference  for the cardview  @jigar savaliya ... in the setUpAndLoadNativeExpressAds()